# MySQL local server does not update PhpmyAdmin when i create databases (mac)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am following a laravel tutorial but when it come to connecting MySQL i have and issue with phpmyadmin

When i create a database from MySQL locally in command line, it does not create it in phpmyadmin and vice versa.
I checked i'm connected with the same user in both side, and i granted the right too.

Do i have to link MySQL locally with phpmyadmin ?

I tried migrations command from my Laravel project, i can see the tables had beed created in MySQL with commandline but nothing happened in phpmyadmin.

here's the video of what i'm trying to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCMgxDfRKCo

Comment: different server?

Comment: Ho, is that possible ? I run mamp on the same port as MySQL locally (3306)

Comment: what? how can you run mamp and mysql on same port?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at phpmyadmin for the SQL database?

Im looking at this video, and maybe you accidentally clicked the Apache Admin button and not the SQL one. thanks @FlashThunder

Comment: I'm using Mamp, so when i start server it automatically run apache on port 80 and mysql on port 3306

Comment: thats perfectly normal. Are you sure you're clicking on the right Database? Sounds like you need to iron some things out, because i personally reckon its already working you just dont think it is lol

Comment: It's working locally with MySQL in command line, but i can't see the databases i created in phpmyadmin, same thing with the otherside, if i create a database in phpmyadmin, i can't see it from command line when i fun show databases;
In the video when he create a database from command line, he can see it in phpmyadmin, i can't.

Comment: really weird, looks like there are 2 databases running, can you check your database data directory and if the same files change when you add a database one and other way?

Comment: i run mysql - u root -p in command line, i checked again when i run my php program i can interact with severals databases i created it's ok, but i don't see nothing in phpmyadmin, it's like MySQL and Phpmyadmin are not connected at all, maybe it's the case ?

Comment: check your phpmyadmin config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured out that the mysql used with MAMP has not the same instance than mysql from command line, i had to modify the .env from my laravel project.

I had to add:

DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

and i can run the mysql of MAMP in command line from this command

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -p

who manage differents databases than when i launch the mysql i installed before MAMP.